# Magento 2.2.2 wysiwyg upload images broken in admin

Tags: magento2.2.2, magento2.2.3

I have tried to upload image in block using wysiwyg editor.

```
1.click the Insert/Edit image
2.choose a image
3.save
```

but image not showing in preview.

Answer (score 0):

for Custom Product text type Attribute:
Inject Magento\Catalog\Helper\Output class in you Block Class.

```
use Magento\Catalog\Helper\Output as ProductAttribute;
class Planlist extends DataObject
{
/**
 * @var ProductAttribute 
 */
private $_productAttribute;
public function __construct(
...
ProductAttribute $productAttribute,
...
) {
...
$this->_productAttribute = $productAttribute;
...
}

/**
     * Prepare product attribute html output
     *
     * @param ModelProduct $product
     * @param string $attributeHtml
     * @param string $attributeName
     * @return string
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.CyclomaticComplexity)
     */
    public function getAdditionalData($product, $attributeHtml, $attributeName)
    {
        return $this->_productAttribute->productAttribute($product, $attributeHtml, $attributeName);
    }
}
```

Call this Function where the need

```
$this->getAdditionalData($item,$item->getData('service_packages'),'service_packages'),
```